# Segre embedding preserves locally closed sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to prove that if $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}^m$ are two locally closed sets, then $S(X \times Y)$ is locally closed in $\mathbb{P}^{(n+1)(m+1) -1}$, where $S(X \times Y)$ is the image of $X \times Y$ through Segre immersion.

If $X$ and $Y$ are locally closed, it means that they are open in their closures $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$. I was trying to prove that $S(X \times Y)$ is open in $S(\bar{X} \times \bar{Y})$ (which is closed because Segre immersion is closed). However, I got stuck here: I am not sure how to prove that $S(\bar{X} \times \bar{Y})$ is the closure of $S(X \times Y)$ and how to prove that $S(X \times Y)$ is open in its closure. Any hints (please do not show me solutions using schemes, I don’t know anything about those)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a sketch:

Write $X$ as the subset of points of $\overline{X}$ where some homogeneous polynomials $f_0,\ldots,f_k$ do not simultaneously vanish. Same for $Y$ with $g_0,\ldots,g_q$. We can assume that all the $f_i$ and $g_j$ have the same degree (up to taking powers). Then you can regard $f_ig_j$ as a homogeneous polynomial in the “bihomogeneous variables” considered in $S: \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{(n+1)(m+1)-1}$.

Then $S(X \times Y)$ is the subset of $S(\overline{X} \times \overline{Y})$ where these polynomials do not simultaneously vanish, so is open in this set.

Comment: Thank you. But why can we assume that $S(\bar{X} \times \bar{Y})$ is the closure of $S(X \times Y)$?

Comment: It doesn’t matter actually: let $T$ be a topological space, let $U \subset T$ be a subset, and let $F \subset T$ be a closed subset containing $U$. Then it’s elementary to show that if $U$ is open in $F$, then $U$ is open in its closure.